# Replace a specific string value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have this table

```
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id    | json_text                                                                |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| aWoJl | {"color":"#1B3451","help_text":"color is here but dont replace me"}      |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| r5Njc | {"color":"#1B3451","help_text":"color is also here but dont replace me"} |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I want to change color value from `#1B3451` to `#1e72d2`. How can I do that?

I have tried using `replace()`, but no result as of now and when trying to use wildcards, it is throwing error.

Here is the SQL fiddle .
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6db3f9/1

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: -- I want to update color value to #1e72d2
UPDATE temptable SET json_text=REPLACE([json_text], '%color:#%','color:#1e72d2')

Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version and why are you still using `[text]` as data type?

Comment: This has been the case since SQL Server 2005, I wish they'd hurry up and pull the trigger already... _The ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead._ Ref: [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql)

Comment: This table is present from long time (It is a sample table). Thats why I dont have the authority to change its datatype

Comment: @JeromeTaylor, if you are using SQL Server 2016+, `JSON_MODIFY` may help: `UPDATE temptable SET json_text = JSON_MODIFY(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), json_text), '$.color', '#1e72d2') WHERE JSON_VALUE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), json_text), '$.color') = '#1B3451'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert first to VARCHAR or NVARCHAR then REPLACE

```
UPDATE temptable set [json_text] = REPLACE(CAST([json_text] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),N'#1B3451',N'#1e72d2');
```